# Create symlink manually

Tags: laravel, symlink, laravel-5.6

I am in shared hosting. I am facing the problem to display image from my storage. I can't access through ssh so can't create symlink with php artisan . Can anyone teach me how to create symlink manually>

Comment: Maybe running [`symlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) will work but there's a good chance the shared hosting provider disallows the running of this command for security concerns

Comment: if hosting provider disallows some of the functions, its probably proc_open() and proc_close() functions. When you contact with providers they are probably allow these function for you in a short time.

Comment: @apokryfos So many functions/commands one can find out every day.

Comment: @apokryfos how can i create manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the route file.

```
    Route::get('example',function() {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

And visit the example.

Comment: I am getting blank page in example

Comment: @naVinShrestha add `echo "Not more blank line\n";` after `Artisan::call('storage:link');`.

Comment: This answer should work, even if you get a blank screen the folder should be linked. If it doesn't it would be worth looking at the logs to see why

Comment: It works. It creates a folder called 'storage' in `/public` (the folder has link icon)